# Oracle SQL - Join 3 tables without duplicating data

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am developing a Person search. So using a persons name I search first to see if they exist in the person table and then if they have any associated Orgs or Regs.

I have 3 tables:

```
PER - (Person)  
ORG - (Organisation)  
REG - (Register Entry)
```

PER is the key table as I want to find all the related ORG's and REG's related to a particular person, there is also a relationship between ORG and REG as an ORG will often (not always) have an associated REG

I currently am joining

```
PER > ORG (Left join) as PER_ORG
PER > REG (Left join) as PER_REG
Then joining PER_ORG > PER_REG (FULL OUTER JOIN)
```

The output should look like

```
PER_NAME        ORG_DETAIL          REG_DETAIL
STUART ADAMS    ADAMS PARTNERSHIP   ADAMS BUSINESS
```

This does return correct results by matching the ORG to the REG when both exist but when a Person exists in PER and only has one related record in either ORG or REG I get duplicated results for the Person.

```
PER_NAME        ORG_DETAIL      REG_DETAIL
STUART ADAMS    NULL            ADAMS BUSINESS
STUART ADAMS    NULL            NULL
```

I understand why I am getting the results I have but I cannot figure out how to eliminate the duplicate Person result when only one related ORG or REG exist.

Put simply the query looks like

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    (SELECT *
    FROM
    PER LEFT JOIN ORG ON PER.PER_ID = ORG.PER_ID
    ) PER_ORG

    FULL OUTER JOIN

    (SELECT *
    FROM
    PER LEFT JOIN REG ON PER.PER_ID = REG.PER_ID
    ) PER_REG

    ON PER_ORG.LINK_ID = PER_REG.LINK_ID
)
```

Comment: Can you post a test case (or, better yet, a SQL Fiddle example) that demonstrates the problem?  If you are getting two rows in your result, that implies that there is a 1:many relationship in one of your joins.  Without data, we can't guess where that 1:many relationship might exist.

Comment: In which tables is the link_id column

Comment: My somewhat wild guess from your description is that an ORG can have multiple RECs (or a REC can have multiple ORGs) and if a person is linked to an ORG but not a REC, you end associating the person with all the RECs that are tied to the ORG.

Comment: @MickyT LINK_ID exists in both ORG and REG

Comment: @JustinCave I have never used fiddle so I am afraid it might take too long for me to play with it to justify the use in this case, but I will try to provide what ever i can to help people understand my problem.
I get two rows in the results in this case because there exists 'Stuart Adams' in PER, and a corresponding REG record. There is no ORG record in this case but because there is still a 'Stuart Adams' so I get an additional row PER details and nulls for ORG. So when I do the outer join I get both rows from the 2 sub query results

Comment: @JustinCave you are spot on

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing something vital, but is there any reason this query wouldn't work:

```
SELECT PER.PER_NAME, ORG.ORG_DETAIL, REG.REG_DETAIL
FROM PER 
LEFT JOIN ORG ON PER.PER_ID = ORG.PER_ID
LEFT JOIN REG ON PER.PER_ID = REG.PER_ID 
           AND ORG.LINK_ID = REG.LINK_ID 
            OR ORG.LINK_ID IS NULL;
```

If it doesn't you can solve your issue by applying `max` to the per_detail and org_detail columns in the outer query and group by the name, like so:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(PER_ORG.PER_NAME, PER_REG.PER_NAME) PER_NAME
    , MAX(ORG_DETAIL) ORG_DETAIL
    , MAX(REG_DETAIL) REG_DETAIL
FROM (
-- removed the rest to save some space...
)
GROUP BY COALESCE(PER_ORG.PER_NAME, PER_REG.PER_NAME)
```